# How to disable Self Control application?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applications

I use SelfControl quite frequently for completing homework and such, but at school, while I was away from my keyboard at the white board, my friend thought it would be funny to set the timer to 10 hours.  I am currently using a proxy to ask this question.  Is there any way to disable this useful, but inflexible application?

Comment: As a note, you should have your computer to ask for a password before making changes. So when I activate my self control program, i have to put my password in first. This will prevent unauthorized of the program.

Comment: the purpose is to not disable it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried opening Terminal (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal) and using the commands:

```
killall SelfControl
```

or

```
sudo killall SelfControl
```

As it is not working try the hosts file:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

And look for something like this

```
# BEGIN SELFCONTROL BLOCK
127.0.0.1   www.nasa.gov
127.0.0.1   nasa.gov
# END SELFCONTROL BLOCK
```

delete the entire block and hit CTRL + O to save the file and CTRL + X to exit.
Everything you put at **hosts** file like:

```
127.0.0.1 facebook.com
127.0.0.1 nasa.gov
127.0.0.1 stackoverflow.com
```

Those addresses will be blocked, you will not be able to access them while they are inside the **hosts** file

To stop and delete SelfControl running as a background process:

```
sudo su -
cd /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/
rm org.eyebeam.SelfControl
```

To delete the firewall rules that have been introduced by SelfControl, read this blog article by Joshua Kehn:

http://joshuakehn.com/2010/10/25/Defeating-SelfControl.html

Comment: Yes. It keeps running even when the application is closed, so killall won't work...

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you

Comment: I have the # BEGIN SELFCONTROL BLOCK and # END SELFCONTROL BLOCK.  What should I do now?

Comment: Delete the entire block and save the file.
There probably be IP numbers and sites addresses inside the block.
if you put:
`127.0.0.1 facebook.com`
for example it will be blocked

Comment: Hit CTRL + O to save the file and CTRL + X to exit

Comment: I did this, and now I can access Google, but every other website is still blocked, and there is nothing in the    /etc/hosts file...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3623/discussion-between-tenshimsm-and-ruddrobinet)

Comment: I wish it was harder than this!

Comment: writing from 2021 here, this app is so restrictive, it would not even let me access zoom on my Mac. What worked for me was 1) delete the hosts in `/etc/hosts` as @msmafra stated above 2) delete the app from my applications folder. 3) use finder to search for `%selfControl%` and delete all matching files. 4) emptied my bin. 5) then restarted my computer. then everything was working fine

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes deleting what's between the `# BEGIN SELFCONTROL` and `# END SELFCONTROL` doesn't work.

On the other side, changing the Date or Time worked perfectly for me! All you gotta do is change your date to something in the future, for example if today is Sep 4 you can change your system date to something like Sep 5 !

1. You open Preferences Open Date & Time
2. Change the date to something like Sep 5 or any date in the future.
3. Open SelfControl, the countdown will be gone now.

Try opening a website that you blocked with selfControl! if it does work! then it's all you gotta do ... otherwise try changing the date back to the original date (Sept 4) for example, and try again opening the website that you blocked with SelfControl!

Comment: You are genius!

Comment: could self control prevent this?

Answer (score 7):

I had to remove the lines in `/etc/hosts`, change the date in `/etc/SelfControl.lock`, and reopen the SelfControl application:

```
sudo sed -i '' '/# BEGIN SELFCONTROL/,/# END SELFCONTROL/d' /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i '' 's|<date>.*|<date>2010-01-01T01:01:01Z</date>|' /etc/SelfControl.lock
killall SelfControl; open -a SelfControl
```

Just deleting `/etc/SelfControl.lock` didn't work. If you have removed SelfControl.app, download it again first.

Comment: At 2020 it is the only answer that works, maybe they update their security policies, Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's simple, just open preferences, and change the date to the next day!

Comment: Changing the time does not work if you are connected to the internet.

Comment: @Mindy How so? I change time often when connected to he network.

Answer (score 5):

Update: This still works in 2021

Quit SelfControl.

Open System Preferences > Date and Time > Change the day 1 day in the future.

Launch SelfControl again. Quit SelfControl and then change the date back.

This works because SelfControl checks the date and time, sees that you are past the blocking period, and removes the host file additions.

Comment: Can confirm this works.

Comment: what about in 2020

Comment: @SuperUberDuper It still works perfectly.

Comment: dang its too easy then(