# Website won't open even after deleting SelfControl

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Self Control application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52588/how-to-disable-self-control-application)

So I deleted SelfControl and when the website still didn't work I did the little terminal command things like killall SelfControl but it said no matching processes were found. I don't know if I should just wait or what. Help please!!!